# Installing Azure Databricks Connect

Tags: azure, databricks, databricks-connect

I am trying to install Azure Databricks Connect following this article:
[Azure Databricks installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect)

I am running:

```
pip3 install --upgrade "databricks-connect==13.1.*"
```

and getting back the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement databricks-connnect==13.1.* (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for databricks-connnect==13.1.*
```

What is wrong? How can I troubleshoot?

Comment: The provided command works for me, but can you try a version without the asterisk expression, such as `pip install --upgrade 'databricks-connect>=13.1,<13.2'`

Comment: @ZachKing, I tried everything: with and without asterisk. I changed version to 12.*.*.  I double checked that my python is 3.11, nothing worked so far.

Comment: Are you installing from pypi directly or you're using some corporate pypi mirror?

Comment: @AlexOtt, I used the following arguments with `pip`, `--trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`. Without them I get SSL error. I always install python libraries with these arguments.